# How to get uniq values of a column into multiple column and another column values its value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi i abelow data and dataframe where ..

**I have a DataFrame values like below:**

```
name        managed_by
host1       sam
host2       sam
host3       sam
host4       sam
host5       Peter
host6       Peter
host7       Jesse
host8       Jesse
host9       Patrick
host10      Banu
host11      Banu
```

**Dataframe:**

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("server.csv", usecols=['name', 'managed_by'])
df2 = df2.value_counts('managed_by')
print(df2)
```

When i run it, it displays below..

```
managed_by
Sam     4
Peter   2
Jesse   2
Patrick 1
Banu    2
```

If Values are like below after pivot the i want all column values to be stripped for `Nan`

```
Sam         Peter   Jesse   Patrick     Banu
host1       host5   host7   host9       host10
host2       host6   host8               host11
host3       Nan     Nan                 Nan
host4       Nan     Nan                 Nan
Nan         host22  Nan                 Nan
host23      Nan     Nan                 Nan
```

**I want below:**

```
Sam         Peter   Jesse   Patrick     Banu
host1       host5   host7   host9       host10
host2       host6   host8               host11
host3       host22                      
host4                           
host23
```

**What i did:**

```
df2 = df2.pivot(columns='managed_by', values='name').replace(np.nan, '')
```

this did worked but if i have huge file then it will fill `Nan` for Blank rows in a column .

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name":["host1","host2","host3","host4","host5","host6","host7","host8","host9","host10","host11"],
    "managed_by":["sam","sam","sam","sam","Peter","Peter","Jesse","Jesse","Patrick","Banu","Banu"]
})

df = df.assign(key=df.groupby(['managed_by']).cumcount()).pivot(
index="key",columns=["managed_by"],values=["name"]).reset_index()

df

           key    name                             
managed_by        Banu  Jesse Patrick  Peter    sam
0            0  host10  host7   host9  host5  host1
1            1  host11  host8     NaN  host6  host2
2            2     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN  host3
3            3     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN  host4


# edit (author wants to strip the NaN values)
df.fillna("")
           key    name                             
managed_by        Banu  Jesse Patrick  Peter    sam
0            0  host10  host7   host9  host5  host1
1            1  host11  host8          host6  host2
2            2                                host3
3            3                                host4
```

Comment: @.. JAdel, thanks for teh answers +1 but that my pivot also works, what i want to strip any `Nan` value for a particular column if its there.

Comment: Then you can use ``df.fillna("")``.

Comment: But `df.fillna("")` will  still make that `Nan` as empty that i don't want and rather want to just clear that `Nan` or empty value so that that there is no gap between column values.

Comment: Its not clear what you exactly want to achieve. Please clearify.